# filtration of a stochastic integral

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

1) Consider the Ito-integral:

$S_t = \int_{0}^{t}f(s)dW_S$, where $f$ is a Borel bounded function and $W$ is a Brownian motion.

Is the $\sigma$-algebra,  $\sigma(S_t) = \sigma(W_s, s\leq t)?$ For sure it is obvious that the inclusion $\subset$ is true by definition of stochastic integral (limit of sums of Brownians). Is the opposite inclusion true?

2) Consider now the case of the Ito-Integral,

$S_t = \int_{0}^{t}f(V_s)dW_S$, with $V$-process satisfying the SDE:

$dV_s = -kV_sdt + \eta dW^V$, with $k, \eta$ constants and $W^V$ correlated to $W$ with correlation $\rho$.

In that case what is the $\sigma$-algebra,  $\sigma(S_t)?$

Thanks!

Comment: 1) No, the opposite inclusion is in general not true. Just consider $f=0$.

Comment: Well I avoided to add corner cases with f=1 or f=0 for obvious reasons. The sigma algebra of $S_t$ can be seen as the sigma algebra of the limsup of sums of brownian increments. So I guess every W_s in [0, t] can be measurable to the filtration of S_t. Not sure though.